# Lagrange Multipliers: "What is a Critical Point?"

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

So we have function $f(x,y) = e^{xy}$ this has the constraint $x^3+y^3=16$ By use of Lagrange Multipliers or the Lagranian we find there is only one critical point at (2,2).

What confuses me alot is that i can't quite grasp what have we exactly found at point (2,2) ?

The constrainted maximum that is closest to the unconstrainted global maximum? This makes no sense since this function has no global maximum nor global minimum.

Comment: It has basically no relation to the global optimization problem. It may be the max or min of $f$ on the set $x^3+y^3=16$.

Comment: @Nulle If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of Wolfram, here's a contour plot of $z=e^{xy}$ (in the white region, $z$ is large; in the red region, it's close to $0$) along with $x^3+y^3=16$ (the blue curve):

[image]

If you are standing at the solution $(2,2)$, you can see that by walking along the constraint, you will be going downhill very quickly. You have found the maximum of $e^{xy}$ subject to the given constraint.

Also note that the point $(2,2)$ is precisely where the tangent of $x^3+y^3=16$ coincides with the tangent of the level curves of $e^{xy}$.

Comment: Thank you this makes lots of sense. However I have also used  Wolfram to this. Can you please try and switch from Maximum to Both. Then we also get a point at (3.32 , -2.75). Which confuses we a hell of alot since when you solve the equations then you clearly get only one solution (2,2) lambda = 9.099... 

So what is (3.32 , -2.75) ?

Comment: There is ofcourse the possibility that i solved wrongly and that there is in fact two solutions.

Comment: @Nulle If you zoom out, you'll see that $x^3+y^3=16$ essentially looks like $x+y=0$ (because for large $x$, we have $y=\sqrt[3]{16-x^3}\approx\sqrt[3]{-x^3}=-x$. Along this line, we have $z=e^{xy}\approx e^{-x^2}\to0$. There is no minimum, since $z>0$ for all $x,y$, but we can make $z$ arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 0):

It's a point of **local extrema** for the function taking into account the constraint.

To verify whether it is a maximum or a minimum you have to calculate the value of "f" at that point and compare with all the others possible max/min values.

From a **geometrical point of view** it's the point where the gradient of $f(x,y)$ ant the gradient of the constrain function $\phi(x,y)=x^3+y^3-16$
 are parallel.

Here is a nice graphical explanation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yS2AlSkIYRY

Comment: And in this case were we only have one critical point. How do we decide wether (2,2) is a local minimum or maximum?

Comment: You have to compare the value with the others possible extrema, e.g. boudary points or irregular points.